# Strange behavior of the first column when adding by VBA multiple formulas to the cells of the MS Word table

Tags: vba, ms-word, formula, cell

Aggregate functions are not added to MS Word table cells if You add an function to a cell in the first column.

```
    Dim myTable As Table

    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Set myTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 5, 6)
    myTable.AutoFormat Format:=wdTableFormatGrid1
    For i = 1 To myTable.Rows.count - 1
        For j = 1 To myTable.Columns.count
            myTable.Cell(i, j).Range.InsertAfter i + j
        Next j
    Next i
    
    With myTable
        .Cell(5, 1).Formula "=SUM(ABOVE)"
        .Cell(5, 2).Formula "=AVERAGE(ABOVE)"
        .Cell(5, 3).Formula "=MIN(ABOVE)"
        .Cell(5, 4).Formula "=Max(Above)"
        .Cell(5, 5).Formula "=Count(Above)"
        .Cell(5, 6).Formula "=Product(Above)"
    End With
```

This code adds all functions in `Cell(5, 1)`, I see the last.
If remove operator
`.Cell(5, 1).Formula "=SUM(ABOVE)"`
, all functions adds to right cells. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. In Microsoft Word, when you add aggregate functions to cells in the first column of a table, the functions are applied only to the cells in the same column and not to the cells above them.

In your code, when you add the function `"=SUM(ABOVE)"` to `Cell(5, 1)`, it calculates the sum of the cells above it in the first column, which includes the cells Cell(1, 1), Cell(2, 1), Cell(3, 1), and Cell(4, 1). The same applies to the other aggregate functions like `AVERAGE, MIN, MAX, COUNT, and PRODUCT.`

However, when you remove the line `.Cell(5, 1).Formula "=SUM(ABOVE)"`, the other aggregate functions are added to the cells in the remaining columns (2 to 6) correctly because there is no function in the first column conflicting with them.

Comment: Thank You TourEiffel,
But if I add .Cell(5, 1).Formula "=SUM(ABOVE)" last (after formulas adding in no first column), the program works fine.